# Google sheets query function will not return alternate rows result counting from second row when data was filtered other from the first instance

Tags: google-sheets

Query formula for Google sheets.
I am extracting data from a machine-generated timesheet. I need to filter out the time for each individual, round the time to rid double clocking, separate clock in time from the out time in the same column, then calculate hours worked.

Other than the first filtered name instance, the time-out column keeps showing the data's from the top filtered row. It supposes to skip the first row and show the second-row value at the clock-out column.

```
=QUERY('Access log list'!D3:G,"Select G where D is not null AND D='" & B5 & "' skipping 2 offset 1",0)
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tJMNbFL-LlP5Z7WDxFaikCmMe7RTdnBHtzOtoc0ztWs/edit?usp=sharing

I tried changing D3:G into D4:G, offset 1 to 4.
Is there a command that asks it to start one row later? It has to be a formula that will not overspill as there will be additional data and calculations below.
Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(QUERY('Access log list'!D3:G,"Select G where D is not null AND D='" & B5 & "' offset 1",0),"select * skipping 2",0)
```

Comment: Thank you  idfurw. Good to learn that you can warp a query onto another query.